# Ant: echo file contents to console with Get task?

Tags: java, ant

Just what the title says - is it possible to echo the response contents without having to store the file?

I would also settle for being able to throw out the results, so a `dest` file is not created (on Windows, so no `/dev/null`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows there are special file called NUL
which has the same function as /dev/null on *nix

(there are also CON, PRN, etc, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)

I think it is possible to use this file as the dest param

```
<get src="http://blahblahblah..." dest="NUL" />
```

If you want to echo the result to the console, you can use CON as the destination

```
<get src="http://blahblahblah..." dest="CON" />
```

I dont know if it is a proper solution in the ant task, but somehow just work.

Comment: Thanks, never knew about those.  NUL works as expected, CON unfortunately gives a '(Access is denied)', but like I said, NUL will do. Hmm, would be nice to have a system independent abstraction over /dev/null & NUL.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the file path in srcfile. the content of the file will be stored into  variable from the given file

```
<loadfile property="content" srcfile="filepath"/>
<echo message="========================================================"></echo>
<echo message="${content}" />
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering in code only. Explain in text and/or comments what you are doing, so that future readers may benefit as well.

Comment: For small files this appears to be the simplest way. I wouldn't do it with large files, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ['Get Task' documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html), I see the 'dest' field is required so I think you're out of luck.